# the wording specific to Australia

Tags: australian-english

Please tell me the wording specific to Australia.

・Carrying on like a pork chop
・Chuck a sickie

etc.

thank you.

Comment: If you *chuck a sickie* then call in sick (take the day off) when you are not really sick. UK speakers usually say *pull a sickie*, just as we say *pull a U-turn*, whereas Australians will says *chuck a Uey*. As for *carrying on like a pork chop*, no idea.

Answer (score 1):

While *chuck* has the usual meaning of "throw", it's often used in Australian English in the sense of carrying out an action (*chuck a uey* = "make a U-turn") or putting on a performance (*chuck a mental* = "throw a wobbly" = lose self-control).

[**chuck a sickie**](http://slll.cass.anu.edu.au/centres/andc/meanings-origins/s)

> A day's sick leave, especially as taken without sufficient medical reason. **Sickie** is an abbreviation of the term *sick leave*, and illustrates a distinctive feature of Australian English — the addition of -ie or -y to abbreviated words or phrases. Other examples include: *firie* ‘firefighter’, *surfie* ‘surfer’, and *Tassie* ‘Tasmania’. **Sickie** is first recorded in 1953, and is often found in the phrase **to chuck a sickie**, meaning ‘to take a day’s sick leave from work’ (often with the implication that the person is not really ill).
>
> - 1962 Bulletin (Sydney) 3 March: I don’t feel a bit like work today… I
>   think I’ll take a sickie.
> - 2003 Canberra Times 21 June: The age old practice of ‘chucking a
>   sickie’ in the Australian Public Service is costing the taxpayer at
>   least $295 million a year.

The injunction "stop carrying on like a pork chop" is typically heard from an exasperated parent when an overtired child puts on a performance because they didn't get what they wanted.

[**carry on like a pork chop**](http://slll.cass.anu.edu.au/centres/andc/meanings-origins/p)

> To behave foolishly, to make a fuss, to complain, or to rant. This expression is often thought to allude to the spluttering noise of a pork chop that is being fried. However it is probably a variant of the older expression **like a pork chop in a synagogue**, meaning something that is unpopular, unlikely, or rare (with reference to the Jewish prohibition of the eating of pork). **To carry on like a pork chop** is first recorded in 1975.
>
> - 2002 *Sunday Telegraph* (Sydney) 10 November: The Australian sports public are a forgiving lot. Ask Lleyton Hewitt. Or Shane Warne. Here are a couple of champions who, on several occasions, have carried on like pork chops.
> - 2003 E. Vercoe *Keep Your Hair On*: She's a beautiful woman, your mother, but by God can she carry on like a pork chop about nothing.